# How to get rid of this repetition of the same value in a column?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In the **miniworld**, we have a course called General Science. It has three modules named Module1, Module2, Module3.

(Each module is covered in 2 months, and then there is an exam, and a final exam in the end of the semester - this is not relevant here, but I am just telling for context.)

In each module, roughly 30% of the course content consists of chapters from physics, 30% from biology and 40% from chemistry. So Physics, Biology and Chemistry are kinda parts (please suggest if you have a better word) of the course.

Each Course_Part is taught by different teachers. So teachers are specialized in one or more of those Course_Parts (i.e. Physics, Biology, Chemistry).

There are several courses like General Science.

........................................................

I have two options. **Please suggest which one will be a better design**:

1. **Make a table/entity type named `COURSE_PART`** ( `CoursePartName`, `Module`,
   `Course`, `(Chapters)` ) and relate it to `TEACHER` by `Teach`, a `N:M`
   relationship.

   *This kinda worries me because there will be a lot of redundant data in the table. Imagine 20 chapters from the same Course_Part in the
   same module, i.e. same CoursePartName repeating 20 times in the
   CoursePartName column, same module name repeating for 20 times in
   the Module column, and same course name repeating for even so many
   more times in the Course column. It doesn't appear good to me.*

   And yes **later I will have to make a separate table called `CHAPTERS`**
   (because it is a multivalued attribute) and include the `primary key`
   of `COURSE_PART` in it as `foreign key`, and it, together with `Chapter`
   attribute will form a composite primary key for `CHAPTERS`. But I
   won't get rid of the kind of ***repetition*** I mentioned.
2. **Make an entity named `COURSE`** with two attributes named `ID` and
   `CourseName`. **Make its week entity named `COURSE_PART`** with attributes
   named `CoursePartName` (same repetition in its column), `Module` (same
   repetition in the module column); and relate it to TEACHER by a `N:M`
   `Teach` relationship?

Is this kind of repetition bad or am I just feeling so? What will be the best way to get rid of this?

Comment: I would say there needs to be 1 teacher table stores all the details for a teacher another table for courses and its detail then a course_part table which as a child table of courses has an association with course_id i.e course_part(id,course_id...) and the junction table to relate the course parts to teacher i.e junction_table(id,course_part_id,teacher_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better name for physics/chemistry/biology might be **Topic**.

Since a topic might be taught as part of multiple modules, it makes sense to have a **Course** table, a **Module** table, a **Topic** table, and a **Content** table to link modules with topics. Content would have a *courseFk* column and a *topicFk* column.

Same with the **Teacher** table: since each teacher can specialise in multiple topics, you can have a **Teaches** linking table.

The linking table strategy will prevent repetition when modelling many-to-many relationships.

With **Chapter** it's a different story: since each chapter belongs to a single topic, your **Chapter** table should have a *topicFk* column.

[image: UMI diagram]